# Why does Ember parent route's actions wont get triggered?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

Router

```
this.route('administration', function() {
  this.route('users', { path: '/' });
  this.route('users');
});
```

routes/administration.js

```
actions: {
    didTransition() {
      console.log('administration didTransition');
    }
}
```

routes/users.js

```
actions: {
    didTransition() {
      console.log('users didTransition');
    }
}
```

When go to url: `localhost:3000/administration/users`

`users`'s `didTransition` got called, but `administration`'s `didTransition` wont get called, can anyone help me on debugging it or the relationship between parent/ children routes?

I'd like to know which lines of code caused such? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out

Ember routes is NOT hitting from`parent -> child`, instead, it uses bubbling up. So by adding `return true;` in the child's `didTransition` function. Child's `didTransition` will bubble up.

Ember will hit `child -> parent`.

routes/users.js

```
actions: {
    didTransition() {
      console.log('users didTransition');
      return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks @dwickern and @mithrilhall